# Pass Data to Model without triggering PropertyChanged-Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and am writting a little test-application using it.
I've got a Model, which represents the data structure -
a ViewModel and a View (parent class is Page), too.

Now i would like to pass some initial data to the Model,
so the window could show me these.

In a [sample application of David Anderson](http://www.danderson.me/posts/mvvm-session-01-02-demo-source-code-downloads/), he passes the data
as method-parameter, which is actually the right way and causes
not the trigger of the PropertyChanged-Event, but my Model-class
is quite "fat" - it gots a lot of properties (> 30).
So, how shall i realize it in this case?
I don't think a method with more then 30 parameters is the right
way to handle that. Or am i wrong?

**Does someone has an idea, how professionals realize this?**

Here is my used code:

**View** (PersonPropertiesView is a subclass of the Page-class)

*XAML*

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

*Code-Behind*

```cs
public PersonPropertiesView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new PersonPropertiesViewModel();
}
```

**ViewModel** (PersonPropertiesViewModel)

*Code*

```cs
private Person _Person;

public Person Person
{
    get
    {
        return this._Person;
    }
}

public Person()
{
    this._Person = new Individual();
    this._Person.ID = 12;
}
```

**Model** (Person, inherits INotifyPropertyChanged)

```cs
private long _ID;

public long ID
{
    get
    {
        return this._ID;
    }
    set
    {
       if (this._ID != value)
       {
           this._ID = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ID");
       }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

If i try to compile this code, i get the System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException exception. Does someone knows why?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264/how-many-constructor-arguments-is-too-many?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first reaction would be: why?  I'm not sure this is too important - when setting these properties immediately after construction, I would imagine it's fairly likely that this occcurs before the ViewModel is bound to any View (though without the context, I couldn't be sure).

The cost of attempting to fire the `PropertyChanged` event with no observers is likely too small to measure.

In the code you've posted, this code will throw an exception when there are no listeners:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You need to check if the event is null, not the property name:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Charles, if i do so, i get an exception of the type "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException". I will post my code, mayby someone will find the mistake.